# GLMM in R versus SPSS (convergence and singularity problems vanish)

Tags: r, spss, lme4, mixed-models, glmm

Unfortunately, I had convergence (and singularity) issues when calculating my GLMM analysis models in R. When I tried it in SPSS, I got no such warning message and the results are only slightly different. Does it mean I can interpret the results from SPSS without worries? Or do I have to test for singularity/convergence issues to be sure?

Comment: https://rdrr.io/cran/lme4/man/convergence.html

Comment: It's really impossible to tell that's going on without more information, but I answered a similar question about the differences between lme4 and SPSS here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/576085/why-does-this-mixed-model-produce-discrepant-output-in-spss-and-r/576128#576128

Answer (score 1):

You have two questions. I will answer both.

##### First Question

> Does it mean I can interpret the results from SPSS without worries?

You do not want to do this. The reason being is that mixed models have a very specific parameterization. Here is a screenshot of common `lme4` syntax from the original [article about lme4 from the author:](https://10.18637/jss.v067.i01)

[image]

With this comes assumptions about what your model is saying. If for example you are running a model with **random intercepts only**, you are assuming that the slopes do not vary by any measure. If you include **correlated random slopes and random intercepts**, you are then assuming that there is a relationship between the slopes and intercepts that may either be positive or negative. **If you present this data as-is without knowing why it produced this summary, you may fail to explain your data in an accurate way.**

The reason as highlighted by one of the comments is that SPSS runs off defaults whereas R requires explicit parameters for the model. I'm not surprised that the model failed to converge in R but not SPSS given that **SPSS assumes no correlation between random slopes and intercepts**. This kind of model is more likely to converge compared to a correlated model because the constraints that allow data to fit a correlated model make it very difficult to converge. However, without knowing how you modeled your data, it is impossible to actually know what the differences are. Perhaps if you provide an edit to your question that can be answered more directly, but just know that SPSS and R do not calculate these models the same way.

##### Second Question

> Or do I have to test for singularity/convergence issues to be sure?

SPSS and R both have singularity checks as a default (check this [page](https://www.ibm.com/mysupport/s/question/0D50z00006PsDjOCAV/lmm-mixed-warning-iteration-terminated-convergence-not-achieved?language=en_US) as an example). If your model fails to converge, you should drop it and use an alternative model (usually something that has a simpler random effects structure or improved optimization).

Comment: Wow thank you so much for this detailed answer! Actually, today I found the difference that led to a warning in R but not in SPSS: While in R I had specified all dichtotomous variables as factors, I defined them as numerical with the values 0 and 1 in SPSS. When I did the same in R, I got the same results and no warnings anymore! Would you say this is appropriate? I was further advised to estimate the random effects as "unstructured" in SPSS, may I ask you what the equivalent in R is; is it the last variant from your screenshot, i.e., (1 | grouping) + (X1 | grouping) + (X2 | grouping)?

Comment: Good to hear. If the model converges, this is a good sign, but whether or not it was done correctly is difficult to guess without the exact code or data you used in your question. In any case I have never heard of unstructured effects before but I assume they mean `x + (x || g)`, which is what I mentioned before as uncorrelated random slopes and intercepts. Someone else can correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @ShawnHemelstrand on the contrary "unstructured" means "general positive definite", so I believe `(1+X1+X2|g)` would be correct ("correlated random intercept and slope[s]" in the table above).  It's quite possible that you will have to choose between (1) **not** using an unstructured formulation (i.e. forcing uncorrelated intercept/slopes) or otherwise simplifying the model (2) living with singularity warnings or (3) getting more data (ha!)

Comment: Thank you for the clarification Ben. Thats useful to know.

Comment: @BenBolker thank you very much for the clarification. Actually, I want to test if  correlations between the random effects exist. Would you advise using your variant then (1+X1+X2|g) in which I assume such a correlation between effects from the start or shouId I go for the "conservative" option ((1|g) + (0+X1|g) + (0+X2|g)) in which I assume them to be independent. I am a bit afraid to bias the estimations if I use the wrong variant. Both options work without convergence issues now.

Comment: If you want to test for correlations among random effects then a likelihood ratio test between models fitted with (a)  `(1+X1+X2|g)` and  (b) `(1+X1+X2||g)` (see the last line of @ShawnHemelstrand's table; it expands to `(1|g) + (0 + X1|g) + (0+X2|g)`) seems most appropriate.